# Python: Using properties of an outer class

Tags: python, inner-classes

I have some code that looks like this:

```
class Log(object):
    @property
    def log(self):
        return self.log

class ExampleClass2(ExampleClass, Log):
    class ExampleClass3(object):
        @property
        def log_value(self):
            self.log.info('Hi!')
```

However I'm getting an error,

```
'ExampleClass3' object has not attribute 'log'
```

I'm guessing I need to add an `__init__()` method to DEF, and I've tried using

```
super(ExampleClass2.ExampleClass3, self).__init__()
```

but I'm still having problems accessing `log`. Any suggestions?

Comment: Don’t use nested classes. There is almost never a reason to do that.

Comment: That being said `print_banana` belongs to the class `DEF`, which inherits `object`, so it does not inherit `print` from the class `BaseClass1`.

Comment: A class definition inside of another does not mean that either class is a descendant of the other.

Comment: you need to provide a minimal example of the code that leads to the error you are getting. the code you have provided will run just fine if you add a `def` in front of the `print_banana` method definition.

Comment: `print 'banana'` indicates that you're using Python 2 without `from __future__ import print_function`, and so `print` is a keyword that cannot be used as the name of a property as you're doing here.

Comment: @jwodder In my actual code I'm not using print, I just used it as an example. I'll modify my question.

Comment: @R.J I'm surprised you're not getting something blowing up earlier because you've decorated a function with the same name as an attribute... (not to mention that class nesting is quite confusing as to what exactly you're trying to do here and why - maybe if you can explain what you want to achieve, someone could possibly point you in the correct way of doing it...)

Answer (score 0):

I believe to get your desired behavior, you need need to pass in an instance of `ExampleClass2` when you create an instance of `ExampleClass3`.

```
class OuterClass:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    class InnerClass:
        def __init__(self, instance):
            self.instance = instance

        def inner_print_value(self):
            print self.instance.value

    def outer_print_value(self):
        printer = OuterClass.InnerClass(self)
        printer.inner_print_value()

OuterClass('Hi').outer_print_value() # 'Hi'
```

As noted in the comments, there is rarely a reason for this kind of structure. It would be easier to create `InnerClass` outside of the definition of `OuterClass`.

```
class OuterClass:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def outer_print_value(self):
        printer = InnerClass(self)
        printer.inner_print_value()

class InnerClass:
    def __init__(self, instance):
        self.instance = instance

    def inner_print_value(self):
        print self.instance.value
```

It seems like you're expecting the value of `self` to be augmented when creating an inner-class, but this is not the case. To do this, you'd want to use inheritance, and that doesn't require nested classes either.